# Can you change the list builder class used by an entity?

Tags: 8, entities

There's an entity created by another module and I'd like to change some of the fields used on a listing page. Currently that page is using the entity's list builder class. Is there a way I can define a new list builder class, make my changes, and use that for this entity? I have tracked this down to where D8 get's entity definition and loads the list builder class from that. I can't find a way to alter the definitions or another way to inject a different class here.

In more specific terms, I have [created an entity with ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and want to override the functionality around `EckEntityListBuilder`.

Answer (score 22):

You want something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] $entity_types */
  $entity_types['node']->setListBuilderClass('Drupal\MY_MODULE\NewListBuilder');
}
```

Comment: I have documented a full working example using Webform at https://blog.dcycle.com/blog/2022-02-07/alter-list-view/

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!