# How do I add a column to the table shown in the vocabulary listing page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I need to add a column to the table shown in the page listing the vocabularies defined for a site. How can I achieve this?

> [image: vocabulary listing]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to override the class generating the list builder output on this page, then fill in the methods with what you want:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['label'] = t('Vocabulary name');
    $header['foo'] = t('Custom Header');
    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $row['label'] = $entity->label();
    $row['foo'] = 'custom_value';
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }
```

See this related question: [Can you change the list builder class used by an entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191508/can-you-change-the-list-builder-class-used-by-an-entity)

So, in essence:

```
function mymodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  /** @var $entity_types \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] */
  $entity_types['taxonomy_vocabulary']->setListBuilderClass('Drupal\mymodule\VocabularyListBuilder');
}
```

Then, in your mymodule/src folder, create a VocabularyListBuilder.php, and copy in from the [core/modules/taxonomy/src/VocabularyListBuilder.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/taxonomy/src/VocabularyListBuilder.php) and modify the two methods above for your output (since they'll be basically identical).

You could also do this with a View page as well, but for archival purposes wanted to explain how this works in general for Drupal core. List builder classes are such a cool and useful new D8 thing.