# How to modify the page at admin/structure/types?

Tags: 8

Using Drupal 8, I'm trying to modify the page at "`/admin/structure/types`" .This page is not a form (instead it is an entity list), so it cannot be modified with **hook_form_alter**.

_entity_list: The value is entity_type. Provides a list of entities using the EntityListController of the respective entity. E.g. _entity_list: view_mode returns the render array of a list of view modes.

Which hook can I use to modify an entity list ?

I have tried

- mymodule_structure_types_prepare_form
- mymodule_structure_prepare_form

and none of those is triggered.

Comment: Why is view-mode tagged for this? Or inline-entity-form?

Comment: sorry I untagged it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see [Can you change the list builder class used by an entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191508/can-you-change-the-list-builder-class-used-by-an-entity)

Using hook_entity_type_alter() you can override the list builder for nodes.

You can add a custom NodeListBuilder in your module that extends or replaces /core/modules/node/src/NodeListBuilder.php

This class is pretty simple, so it should be easy to add or remove rows to the table displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Inside \core\modules\node\node.routing.yml you can see that the path "admin/structure/types" is having defaults: _entity_list

From https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes I can see that:

> **_entity_list**: The value is entity_type. Provides a list of entities using the EntityListController of the respective entity. E.g.
>   _entity_list: view_mode returns the render array of a list of view modes.

So, the question would be to modify the output of this EntityListController.

Update:
Apparently this has already been answered , as other people suggested.

I just found this. It might be helpful as a complete example.
[How do I add a column to the table shown in the vocabulary listing page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213793/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-the-table-shown-in-the-vocabulary-listing-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using hook_clone_entity_load( $entities, $type), and when the type==block I am on that page

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you share the code.. ?