# how to add .js programatically when in an entity list

Tags: 8

I'm in the hook_entity_load in my module and I want to dynamically add a .js library which I already have defined.
The thing is i need to get to  the block objec I'm on to add the library using $block['#attached']['library'][]

How do I get this block object?

Comment: Why in the load hook and not when the entity is viewed with hook_entity_view() What entity is this? In most cases, just because the entity is loaded doesn't mean it is used/displayed.

Comment: its a list of entities .  I need to add .js under special conditions when i'm on a list of entities.

Answer (score 3):

The correct approach is doing it using a custom list builder, assuming you are using that and not a view.

```
class MyListBuilder extends EntityListBuilder {

  public function render() {
    $build = parent::render();
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/library';
  }
}
```

Then specify it in the annotation of your entity type.see Node/User or so on how to do that, most entity types specify either the default or a custom list builder.

If it's a view then you can implement one of the many views hooks, if it's not your own entity type then I'm not exactly sure why you need to add a JS there and you should explain in more detail what kind of list it is and what your JS does.

Comment: can you show me an example of where in the module to put this class?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you add it, you just have to put the right definition into the annotation. As I said, there are plenty of examples, almost every core enitty type has a list builder.

Comment: sounds like this is basically the same question as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231153/how-to-modify-the-page-at-admin-structure-types. then it is a separate entity type, and instead of adding to the annotation, you need to implemnt hook_entity_type_alter() as commented there and extend NodeTypeListBuilder