# How to sort the content types/bundles on /node/create page

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to reorder the list of available content types on the create content page.
I have node-add-list.html.twig and entity-add-list.html.twig inside my custom theme template folder.
Twig then outputs the array of all types or bundles/content types in alphabetical order. How can I sort this a different way? And can I hard code the links I want in this file or can I output each content type individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in preprocess by overriding this code from *node.module*:

```
function template_preprocess_node_add_list(&$variables) {
  $variables['types'] = array();
  if (!empty($variables['content'])) {
    foreach ($variables['content'] as $type) {
      $variables['types'][$type->id()] = array(
        'type' => $type->id(),
        'add_link' => \Drupal::l($type->label(), new Url('node.add', array('node_type' => $type->id()))),
        'description' => array(
          '#markup' => $type->getDescription(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can replace the foreach loop in the twig template

*node-add-list.html.twig*

```
  <dl>
    {% for type in types %}
      <dt>{{ type.add_link }}</dt>
      <dd>{{ type.description }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
  </dl>
```

with a hard-coded list:

```
  <dl>
      <dt>{{ types.article.add_link }}</dt>
      <dd>{{ types.article.description }}</dd>
      <dt>{{ types.page.add_link }}</dt>
      <dd>{{ types.page.description }}</dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: I see how you can edit the page, but how would you specifically sort the content types with these methods?

Comment: you would have to reorder the array `types` in preprocess, for example reverse the order `$variables['types'] =  array_reverse($variables['types']);
`

Comment: THanks 4k4. {{ types.article.add_link }} This works on a plain Drupal site. Now I am trying it on another site that has the Group module and workbench. I think when using the group module it uses the template entity-add-list.html.twig for site authors instead of  node-add-list.html.twig. And the output is {{ bundle.add_link }}<p>{{ bundle.description }} instead of {{ type.add_link }}{{ type.description }}. So I tried {{ bundle.article.add_link }}{{ bundle.article.description }} but it did not work. I dont think the output for bundle is coming from the node.module #501 because that uses type

Comment: This is the generic entity add list. Try plural of bundle: `{{ bundles.article.add_link }}`. You should also be able to manipulate the `bundles` array in preprocess: `mytheme_preprocess_entity_add_list()`

Comment: Thanks I did try the plural but it didn't work. I will try mytheme_preprocess_entity_add_list()

Comment: Just thinking that this was easy in Drupal 7.I went to the
Navigation menu and changed the order, then went to /node/add/ page and the new order is displayed. In D8 I went to Administration menu and changed the order and saved it. The order is saved but If I look at the /node/add/ page it still has the old order? This is just something I wanted to test. I am not using types, I am using bundles instead. and instead of the  /node/add page I have /group/7/node/create/

Comment: Yes, try the preprocess and check the content of variables. Should be not problem to find this out. I don't use the group module, so I can't help.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately not so easy.
Please take a look,
I've already answered that in a previous question.

[How to modify the page at admin/structure/types?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231153/how-to-modify-the-page-at-admin-structure-types/231155#231155)