# How to modify the link titles shown in /node/add page?

Tags: 8, navigation

I can modify the menu item title implementing the [hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x) hook, as illustrated in this screenprint:

[image]

I changed the menu item title to "*Article (Only One Article can be created and edited)*".

But the problem is that the same item is shown also in the `/node/add` page but the title of that link is not changed because it is shown by a controller. As illustrated in the above image also, the menu links are changed but the link in the `/node/add` page remains without changes, which is still just "*Article*".

How I can change that value also, i.e from "*Article*" to "*Article (Only One Article can be created and edited)*", so that it matches with the menu item title?

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232043/how-to-sort-the-content-types-bundles-on-node-create-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should copy [template_preprocess_node_add_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node_add_list/8.2.x) into your module or theme and customize.  I would advise against trying to change the value in the node type because it's the name of the bundle type across the site.  It will show many places you don't want to update.

For example, to update the article link:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node_add_list(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['content'] as $type) {
    if ($type->id() == 'article') {
      $variables['types'][$type->id()] = array(
        'label' => $type->label() . ' (Only one article can be created and edited)',
        'type' => $type->id(),
        'add_link' => \Drupal::l($type->label() . ' (Only one article can be created and edited)', new Url('node.add', array('node_type' => $type->id()))),
        'description' => array(
          '#markup' => $type->getDescription(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Another alternative to the preprocess function is just to copy /core/modules/node/templates/node-add-list.html.twig into your theme and add your custom rules there.

**UPDATE:**

Due to the question's particular requirements, I'm adding another solution that works without altering the seven theme (that conflicts with my solution above).  In the solution below, we alter the output of $node_type->label() conditionally:

```
function mymodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node_type']->set('label_callback', 'mymodule_node_type_label');
}

function mymodule_node_type_label(NodeType $type) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'node.add_page' && $type->id() == 'article') {
    return $type->get("name") . ' (You can only add one of these)';
  }
  return $type->get("name");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's another solution that works with the seven theme.  You can alter the particular node types you like in the preprocess function in your custom module.  This will only alter their labels within this context.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node_add_list(&$variables) {
  $article_type = $variables['content']['article'];
  $variables['content']['article']->set('name', $article_type->get('name') . ' (Only one article can be created and edited)');
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm doing a custom module, not a custom theme, the problem is that  if seven theme is active it use another variables for the template and always rewrite the module_preprocess variables.

Comment: take a look inside seven_preprocess_node_add_list and you will see

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the 'label' key.  I think you will need to create a new admin theme to get this approach to work.  Or copy seven and customize as a custom admin theme.

Comment: 'emptied' is change the code in the seven theme?

Comment: Sorry I changed the comment.  So you want this module to a contrib module, so it has to work with every theme?

Comment: Yes, the module is in https://www.drupal.org/project/onlyone. The problem is that the seven preprocess function is called after the module preprocess, So I'm searching now how to give more relevance to the module preprocess function, any idea?

Comment: This is the issue with the feature request for the module https://www.drupal.org/node/2860649 in Drupal 7 is done, so I'm trying to do the same in D8

Comment: I have added another solution where you conditionally update the node label on that page.  There is an issue with this solution, as is it adds a label callback to the NodeType entity.  This is pretty unusual, so you could just add a comment in your README.md file to watch out for conflicts with other contrib modules.  Or better yet, just add a node-add-list template and instructions on how to remove that code from the seven theme that's overriding this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I give you credit in the issue :-) https://www.drupal.org/node/2860649

Answer (score 2):

While @oknate answer is perfect for the original question, in this case an approach in a module could be to replace the NodeController class with a custom class, and use in `addPage()` a custom template or return a build array with the links directly:

**NodeController::addPage()**

```
$build = [
  '#theme' => 'node_add_list_custom',
  ...
  ],
];
```

Then set the custom controller class for the route `node.add_page` in a [RouteSubscriber](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) .

Comment: This is a workable solution, but is not ideal for a contrib module.

Comment: @oknate, I agree, your second update is the best solution, overwriting the value in the object (btw. if you put the object in a variable, you can use set() on it, because objects are always a reference). I would upvote again, if it was possible.